# Would Google penalize me for removing indexed pages?

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing, penalty

I'm about to remove a large part of a website in order to replace it by a better alternative which, unfortunately, cannot be mapped to older URIs with URL rewriting.

The part of the website I want to remove is indexed by Google.

Would Google penalize me for removing indexed pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Google won't penalize your site for removing a part of it, you can do it.

However, if you can't redirect old URLs from the new ones, mark your old URLs as Gone (410 HTTP status) with an *.htaccess* file (if you use Apache as a web server).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Google will penalize for removing indexed pages. If you remove the indexed pages, it will show a 404 not found error. You will have to redirect the removed page URL's to relevant pages of your website. I understand that you might be facing some limitations. But, it's a must.

If you don't do it, 404 not found error list will keep growing in the webmaster account which isn't a good sign.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, another answer is opposite to yours. May you, please, comment on that, or edit your answer to include references?

Comment: It will penalize (or rather remove) those specific urls, it wont penalize the ranking of your site overall.